# Titling: Unwanted Font Change in scrbook

Tags: titles, koma-script

I can't figure out why the "maketitle" font uses a different font than the selected global document font. The reason why I used the "maketitle" title is to be able to use the \lowertitleback command which is exclusive to scrbook. 
MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=9cm:16cm,pagesize=pdftex]{scrbook}  

\usepackage{imfellEnglish}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lettrine}


\begin{document}

 \begin{titlepage}
  \vspace*{2cm}
  \begin{center}

\textbf{\Huge \textsc{My LaTeX Story}}
\end{center}
 \end {titlepage}

\title{My LaTeX Story}
\author{}
\date{}
 \lowertitleback{\noindent \copyright 2019} 

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use

```latex
\addtokomafont{title}{\rmfamily}
```

to avoid the switch to the sansserif font for font element `title`.

If you do not want the usage of `\sffamily` for other font elements too, set class option `sfdefaults=false`:

```latex
\documentclass[paper=9cm:16cm,
  sfdefaults=false% <- added, needs version 3.39 or newer
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{imfellEnglish}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

 \begin{titlepage}
  \vspace*{2cm}
  \begin{center}

\textbf{\Huge \textsc{My LaTeX Story}}
\end{center}
 \end {titlepage}

\title{My LaTeX Story}
\author{}
\date{}
 \lowertitleback{\noindent \copyright 2019} 

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional remark: It is not recommended to use package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class.

Comment: +1 for `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`

Comment: For koma  v3.39 or newer there is now the class option `sfdefaults=false` instead of `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the hint.